# How to pass variable from js to php in PayPal checkout Integration?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I'm creating a shopping site with HTML and PHP. It's my first time doing web development.

I'm trying to add PayPal Checkout to my site. I got the code from paypal developer and it works payments are successful. 
If the payment is successful I need to insert order data into my database with php.

How do I pass a javascript variable defined by me indicating the payment approval to PHP?

I've seen it done with ajax but I dont know how to implement it.

Here is my code. I added the jquery CDN since it seems to be necessary but I don't know if need anything else.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <!-- Add meta tags for mobile and IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({
            
            style: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                color: 'blue',
                shape: 'rect'
            },
            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: '17'
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },

            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                    
                    //Variable to confirm successful payment on php
                    //?
                    //?
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data that gets returned by the javascript? What comes back from PayPal? JSON, perhaps? This question is a little too broad to answer as it is now.

Comment: @tshimkus I want to use a custom variable defined by me inside the payment capture. Then validate if that variable is true for example in a php file to make queries.

Comment: Is there a callback coming from PayPal back to your site somehow? There are so many ways this could be handled. It would be helpful to those that might attempt to help you if you could be as specific as possible and provide a concrete example of the response you receive from PayPal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP can only be seen on the server. So you should send a value to the server with [fetch (recommended)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Create a PHP file in which you can receive a `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable and process the rest of the payment. In this example I call the file `ajax_file.php`, but you can name it whatever you want.

Add the `fetch` to your `onApprove` method. We'll be sending with the `POST` method so that it is a bit easier to send data through the `body` property. `GET` can do it too but works a little bit different.

```
// Finalize the transaction
onApprove: function(data, actions) {                
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // Show a success message to the buyer
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');

        // URL which to send the value to.
        const url = 'http://yoursite.com/ajax_file.php';

        // Message to send. In this example an object with a state property.
        // You can change the properties to whatever you want.
        const message = { status: 'success' };

        // Send it to the URL with the POST method 
        // and send the message in JSON format.
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(message)
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error); // Display error if there is one.
        });

    });
}
```

And in your PHP file, for example `ajax_file.php`.
There you check the value. See if it's sent and if it's the right value and continue the flow from there.

```
// Check if status send.
$status = isset( $_POST[ 'status'] ) ? $_POST[ 'status' ] : false;

// Check the value of status
if ( $status === 'succes' ) {

    // Status is a success.
    // Continue your form flow.

}
```

It's not clear in your question what should happen next, but I hope you can figure that out from here.